# Get status between user click and user delete/remove in NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Now, my app receive **notification** from **Firebase** and I use **NotificationListenerService** for get event when received and delete/remove notification. it's works fine.

But in **onNotificationRemoved** I want to know status of notification close by **user click open** or **delete** it. What should I do??

Help me please.

This is my code 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When posting a notification with help of notificationCompat builder, you can set "DeleteIntent" in it you can set PendingIntent with broadcast receiver to get the broadcast whenever user delete or swipe out your notification.

Comment: I haven't search posting notification method in my app because it's send from firebase and set every thing in php file body such as title etc. Where I can use notificationCompat builder?